# Regex.IsMatch handle null values

Tags: c#

I am trying to match Regex in if condition where sometime value can be null. But the problem is when it returns null the `Regex.IsMatch(UPC, @"^\d+$")` throws exception as you can see in picture bellow `Value can not be null`. So my question is how can i fix my if condition so it will not throw exception on null value?

c# code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseStr);
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
string UPC = "";
string EAN = "";
if (doc.Descendants(ns + "Ack").FirstOrDefault().Value != "Failure")
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch((string)doc.Descendants(ns + "UPC").FirstOrDefault(), @"^\d+$"))
    {
        UPC = (string)doc.Descendants(ns + "UPC").FirstOrDefault();
    }
    if (Regex.IsMatch((string)doc.Descendants(ns + "EAN").FirstOrDefault(), @"^\d+$"))
    {
        EAN = (string)doc.Descendants(ns + "EAN").FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

error picture:

https://ibb.co/ko5bve

Comment: Why won't you check the value before using RegEx?

Comment: You shouldn't use `FirstOrDefault` this way. It may return null value and result into `NullReferenceException` or `ArgumentNullException`. Instead, you need to check and for null manually or use `First()` and handle `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Regex.IsMatch((string)doc.Descendants(ns + "EAN").FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty   .... This should work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't *call* the method with a null value. Store the value from the XML in a local variable first, then you can use the same variable to easily:

- Check for null
- Check against the regex
- Copy it to another variable

Sample code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseStr);
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
string upc = "";
string ean = "";
if (doc.Descendants(ns + "Ack").FirstOrDefault().Value != "Failure")
{
    string candidateUpc = (string) doc.Descendants(ns + "UPC").FirstOrDefault();        
    if (candidateUpc != null && Regex.IsMatch(candidateUpc, @"^\d+$"))
    {
        upc = candidateUpc;
    }
    string candidateEan = (string) doc.Descendants(ns + "EAN").FirstOrDefault();        
    if (candidateEan != null && Regex.IsMatch(candidateEan, @"^\d+$"))
    {
        ean = candidateEan;
    }
}
```